# How to export data from Cassandra to CSV file using Java

Tags: java, cassandra-2.0

I tried to use the [DataStax Java Driver](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver), but then i found out it does not support the `COPY` command, does anyone know other methods of exporting data using Java? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example i have created event table:

```
cqlsh:kunderatest> describe TABLE event ;

CREATE TABLE event (
  id text,
  log text,
  timstamp bigint,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

and inserted three record

```
cqlsh:kunderatest> INSERT INTO event (id, log , timstamp ) VALUES ( '1', 'my first log' , 12345678);
cqlsh:kunderatest> INSERT INTO event (id, log , timstamp ) VALUES ( '2', 'my second log' , 12345679);
cqlsh:kunderatest> INSERT INTO event (id, log , timstamp ) VALUES ( '3', 'my third log' , 12345680);
```

**1)** First you can do it by using CQLSH client. Now you can export the data of event table into any file (in this case it is log.txt) by executing following command.

```
cqlsh:kunderatest>  COPY kunderatest.sample (id, name, age, address) TO './log.txt' WITH DELIMITER = '|' AND QUOTE = '''' AND ESCAPE = '''' AND NULL = '<null>';
3 rows exported in 0.042 seconds.
```

You can validate the command output by verify log.txt file. Hope it will help you.

**2)** Second you can also use Runtime utility of Java to execute the export command in order to achieve the goal.

- create a file (let say command.txt) and paste the following export command into that file.

  ```
  COPY kunderatest.sample (id, name, age, address) TO './log.txt' WITH DELIMITER = '|' AND QUOTE = '''' AND ESCAPE = '''' AND NULL = '<null>'
  ```

after creating the file and adding the above command into that file do the following it will export the data into file which is given in export command.

```
    String exportCommand = cassandraHome + "bin/cqlsh " + hostname + " " + rpcPort + " -f command.txt"; // file which holds export command

    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process process = runtime.exec(exoprtCommand);

    // for keep tracking the log, you can do following. 
    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line = null;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {

    }
```

Note: cassandrahome is path of cassandra package directory. in my case it is /usr/local/apache-cassandra-2.0.6